# How to change the colors of text and background for cmd in Java?

Tags: java, text, colors, background, cmd

I have been doing Java for a while now and I have never seen a tutorial on how to make cmd change colors of text and background. In C++ you can just use SetConsoleTextAttribute(); and it will change the color of bg and text. Is there a class you import in Java to allow you to do that, or is there a third party API that you have to download? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Download jansi-1.4.jar and Try This code 100% working :

```
import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole;
import static org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.*;
import static org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.Color.*;

public class Sample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    AnsiConsole.systemInstall();

    System.out.println(ansi().fg(RED).a("Hello World").reset());
    System.out.println("My Name is Raman");

    AnsiConsole.systemUninstall();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ANSI escape code http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

```
System.out.println("\033[6mHello world");
```

may not work on your console though...

Answer (score 0):

If this is for use with windows(cmd) specifically then:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "color XX").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
```

should give you the result you are after.

Where XX is the color code corresponding to the background and text color that you want to use.